# Unable to Create an Australian Paypal Developer Account

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I would like to create a paypal developer account for myself, however it seems that the developer account registration only accepts US addresses.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use a fake US address. You don't need to attach any bank accounts or credit cards to a developer account, so this is a harmless way of getting around Paypal's stupid and arbitrary new developer rules.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I couldn't find a way around this either, being a UK developer, so had to put a US address in.... I used [http://www.fakenamegenerator.com](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-random-en-us.php) to get a 'valid' telephone number and zip code to get the form to work.

PayPal really seem to miss the point if you are outside the US, despite the same page promoting that you can use the service in over 190 markets and 25 currencies...